# Druid / Tranquility (server) / Ingestion / Indexing has not finished

Tags: indexing, real-time, druid, data-ingestion

I use Druid 0.9.1.1 & Tranquility 0.8.0, and I followed the quickstart steps here: http://druid.io/docs/0.9.1.1/tutorials/quickstart.html

The following command succeed:

```
bin/generate-example-metrics | curl -XPOST -H'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary @- http://localhost:8200/v1/post/metrics
```

It returns this response:

```
{"result":{"received":25,"sent":25}}
```

... and through Druid console I could see the indexing task got created:

[image: Druid Console page]

Problem is: the datasource (named metrics, per spec I have in the schema) hasn't showed up, been 20 minutes now. The indexing is still in RUNNING state.

Why it's taking so long? So I checked this: http://druid.io/docs/latest/ingestion/stream-push.html . Fast forward to the "Task creation" section, it says:

> The segmentGranularity is the time period covered by the segments produced by each task. For example, a segmentGranularity of "hour" will spawn tasks that create segments covering one hour each.

Could it be the reason why I haven't seen my datasource (the value of segmentGranularity in my schema spec is 1 HOUR)?

[image: Schema spec]

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yep, figured out it was really the case. After 1 hour and 15 minutes the indexing task is finished, and I can see my datasource (with the newly-added segment).

Comment: The datasource should show up fairly quickly if no changes were made to dimensions and metrics.   The behavior was pretty confusing initially when I started using Druid.